# SVN BRANCH Strategy to deal with isolated ISSUES

Tags: svn, versioning

Currently on the project I'm working on, we just put a TRUNK, TAG, BRANCH structure to be prepared to versioning. Since there's around 10 developer working on separate ISSUES we are wondering which should be the best strategy to push ahead.

A particularity of this project is that at the end of the day any ISSUE that is resolved must be deployed to INTEGRATION, HOMOL and PROD after tested.

But we are talking about have control on any ISSUE in the way we could chose which one must be promoted.

To create a separated BRANCH for each ISSUE should be the solution?

Should we maintain a BRANCH for INTEGRATION, HOMOL aside TRUNK to reflect the promotions?

There's a well known recipe for this scenario that you guys could share?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the other questions, but I think the answer to,

```
Should we maintain a BRANCH for INTEGRATION, HOMOL aside TRUNK to reflect the promotions?
```

is, no.  I believe whatever is deployed to the initial environment should be deployed to the subsequent environments.  My definition of "promoting" is simply moving (the binary, installer, TAR'd web directory, etc...), not checking out and rebuilding for every new environment.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you're asking how to actively develop with unstable changes, and then later mark a change as ready for other people to use. So you need some place in your repository that is always "clean".

I've seen a couple ways to do this. One way, is to always create a branch for every ISSUE (I used all caps only because you did in your question, I really don't know why). Once the fix for the ISSUE is fully coded, tested, and maybe peer reviewed, you can merge the branch for ISSUE back to trunk. With this strategy, trunk itself is always "clean" but there will be a lot of merging.

The other way I can think of immediately, is to create a separate "stable" directory, either beside trunk or in the branches directory. When you feel like a group of issues on trunk is ready to go, do a cherry-pick merge of just the issues that are ready over to "stable". Now the stable directory is always "clean" but trunk may have work-in-progress or broken things. There are fewer merges this way because you can do it in batches, but it can require more work to track which changes are actually included on stable and which are not, and the nature of cherry-picked merges means that you risk breaking something by leaving out a required change in a revision you did not merge.